# 2 computers one git issue

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a issue with bitbucket recently in the way that if i use my computer from work in order to do a ssh on a server and then do a git pull everything is perfect, but if I do this from my home computer, into the same server, i get :

> repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

This is super strange and I don't know what to do in this case.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 
bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/bitbucket type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/bitbucket-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
conker_1.0.310-c404db1 app-153
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.310-c404db1 app-153
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: xxx@xxx.xx
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
authenticated via a deploy key.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

xxx/xxx: production_server -- xxx@xxx.xx
xxx/yyy: production_server -- xxx@xxx.xx
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3184, received 2008 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17457.1, received 11009.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Somehow I have the impression that at home I am passing the local SSH keys to the server or there is a mix of things anyway.
Does anyone have an idea why I am having this? How can I stop it? Thank you

Comment: Have you registered the key from your home computer on your bitbucket account?

Comment: yes, but this is used only for my personal projects. the server has a deployment key

Comment: @Morpheus_ro Bitbucket (or GitHub) needs to know what your public key is, and you have to tell it what it is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you be more specific? I didn't get the part with the 'public key is'? I mean it is a key and it is specified in the config file locally and on the server with the deployment key.

Comment: Look into adding multiple SSH keys into your Bitbucket account.  Unless the same public key coincidentally happens to be used at home and at work, you'd need to tell Bitbucket about both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I added to the config file

> IdentitiesOnly yes

so the ssh config file looks like:

```
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

to the server and this is working now.